# syntax error and string words together. Print command

Tags: python

```
 # Reading line of text
   text = input("Enter text: ")
   print("English: " ,text)

 # Removing punctuation
   text = removePunctuation(text)

 # Converting to lower case
   text = text.lower()


 # Iterating over words
  for word in text.split(" "):

 # Converting word to Pig Latin form
   word = pigLatin(word)

 # Printing word
   print(word, end = " ");
```

How can I get it to say `Pig:` and then the Pig Latin form?  Every time i try this, it just adds the Pig Latin transformation to the previous word.

Comment: `print(word, pigLatin(word))`?

Comment: How does pigLatin() work? It seems like if it works properly, then it should print the correct thing.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please [edit] your question to include the full error and any additional code that may be relevant (like `pigLatin()`). These are parts of providing the [mcve] that we need to help.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to make one variable do two things at once.
If you want to use the old value later (in your print) then quit destroying the original value:

```
pl_word = pigLatin(word)
print (word, pl_word)
```

Comment: I'm fairly confident this does not fix the issue. Re-using the variable is not an issue since every iteration of the loop `word` is reset. It's still unclear exactly what the OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Pig:", word)
```

Next time, please use capital letters and some markdown... https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help